# get Asset UriString

Tags: android, uri, inputstream, assets

I look for a solution to replace 
 Images. Media. EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI (type String uriString)  by my asset

```
        InputStream ims = getAssets().open("a.jpg");
        // load image as Drawable
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        Bitmap bitmap=drawableToBitmap(d);
        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse( Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI + "/"  );
        bitmap = ImageLoader.loadFromUri( this, imageUri.toString(), 1024, 1024 );

        mImageView.setImageBitmapReset( bitmap,0,true);
```

thank

Comment: You want to replace `Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` with what? And why are you not able to do so?

Comment: i want replace this value Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI because my image is in a folder asset and i use a script which take random image in Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI but i want change this script and to can put my asset

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
File file = new File("path_to_image_file");
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

Comment: i want to try this InputStream ims = getAssets().open("a.jpg");
       File file = new File(ims.toString());
       Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file); but doesn't work